# How to check if an element has continuous element python

Tags: python, list

(We know what element we want to be continuous, say 0)

Say there was a list

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10]
```

I want to count the number of continuous "groups" of 0 (in this case 2) how many 0's are in the group (2, 3) and its two surrounding numbers ([1, 2], [9, 10]) (if at the end return one number plus saying "end"/"start"). I want to do it quickly without using many for loops. So in the end the out put would be:

```
[2, [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10]]
```

The format of the final output would be [number of groups of 0's, [length of 0's, surrounding to the right, surrounding to the left], [other groups...]]

Comment: Pretend to be the computer.  Do this with paper and pencil.  Then you can convert to a program.  It just takes one pass through the numbers.  Keep track of the last non-0 you found, and keep track of the numbers of 0s since then.

Comment: How large is the data likely to be?  It's likely not worth spending the time needed to 'optimize' handling a list of 10 numbers.

Comment: the list can be as big as 10^5

Comment: What does the first 2 in the output mean?

Comment: What of a streak of zeros isnt surrounded by two nonzeros?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy the number of groups of 0s

Comment: @KellyBundy then it would be part of the continous group

Comment: Why would you include the number of groups on the output? That's redundant.

Comment: What does "the be part of the continous group" mean? What should the result be if the input didn't have that final 10?

Comment: [3, 9, "end"] would be it

Comment: What happens when a single 0 is surrounded by non-zeros?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all these answers to comments.

Comment: And for input [0,0,0], output should be [1,[3,"start","end"]]?

Comment: yes it would be that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can user `itertools.groupby` and keep track of the previous group of zeros and previous group of non-zeros. When you see a group of non-zeros (so long as you've see some zeros, yield your result). At the end you can take the length of the list and prepend it to your result:

```
from itertools import groupby

def zero_groups(l):
    current, prev, isZero = None, "start", None
    
    for isZero, g in groupby(l, key=lambda n: n== 0):
        c = list(g)
        if isZero:
            current = len(c)
        else:
            if current:
                yield [current, prev, c[0]]
            prev = c[-1]            
    if isZero:
        yield [current, prev, "end"]


l = [1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10]
groups = list(zero_groups(l))  
[len(groups), *groups]
# [2, [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10]]

# leaving off the length for these edges cases:

list(zero_groups([0, 0, 0]))
# [[3, 'start', 'end']]

list(zero_groups([1, 2, 3]))
# []

l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0]
list(zero_groups(l))
# [[3, 'start', 1], [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10], [3, 10, 'end']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def solution1(numbers):
    result = [0]
    for k, [*g] in groupby(['start', *numbers, 'end'], bool):
        if k:
            if g[0] != 'start':
                result[0] += 1
                result.append([zeros, before, g[0]])
            before = g[-1]
        else:
            zeros = len(g)
    return result

def solution2(numbers):
    prev = 'start'
    result = [0]
    for x in numbers + ['end']:
        if x:
            if not prev:
                result[-1].append(x)
        else:
            if prev:
                result[0] += 1
                result.append([1, prev])
            else:
                result[-1][0] += 1
        prev = x
    return result

tests = [
    [1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 3],
]
for numbers in tests:
    for f in solution1, solution2:
        print(f(numbers))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVPBbsIwDD3s1q_wTm0hTJRp0obEl0Q5UJF0FSWpEncq-5EdduGyfdS-ZkmaFgoDLYoUOXbes5_jz-96j69KHg5fDYrZ88_dh9BqByVyjUpVBspdrTRCoVVT5_so2nABRlUNlkpmiWx2OdcmXUZgl-amqRBWQOfMXwilYUuATgoGpexBEhobXGuMCUwCAIGYy03MCOSWNcC5VQrYHq1wU1h8uF9BgBn7j4m4qOkKsivuh3VdW9KEvnOtbAY5t-ly4tFZOnrUuWxhBZ1lbHDxyvAxuYeycRWXSZEGUbDRMnCO9Vuc6Vdr_gZDWdclbZ2Y4SlMgXbajURrL0STCj3BVbVsZb0kbXqjRot1E-efqmfEw5wpfUk3zvACPWjW_qU1coOuG9Q7HePc7wWBJwIvvWl3NmekC3LGrTh7nISempl_8GhNFrku9Q2yvfKJLIf-CXc3DBE5_oflSVmlxEQMHyTt5jOMaT-uvw)):

```
[2, [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10]]
[2, [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10]]
[4, [1, 'start', 1], [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10], [1, 10, 'end']]
[4, [1, 'start', 1], [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10], [1, 10, 'end']]
[1, [3, 'start', 'end']]
[1, [3, 'start', 'end']]
[0]
[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best solution I can think of it's `O(n)`.

it will loop over the list 1 time and find all the groups of 0.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
count = 0  # count current number of continuous 0

out = [0]

for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == 0:  # if the number is 0 increase current group counter
        count += 1
    elif count == 1:  # if the number isn't 0 and the count is 1, this isn't a group
        count = 0
    elif count > 1:  # if the number isn't 0 and counter is bigger than 1, it is the end of a group
        if i - count - 1 >= 0:
            out.append([count, l[i - count - 1], l[i]])
        else:
            out.append([count, "start", l[i]])
        count = 0
if count > 1:  # there was another group of 0 but no element after the group
    if len(l) - count - 1 >= 0:
        out.append([count, l[len(l) - count - 1], "end"])  # add a list with only the element before
    else:
        out.append([count, "start", "end"])  # add a list without element before and after
out[0] = len(out) - 1  # insert number of groups

print(f"{out = }")

# --------- output ---------
# [1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10] -> out = [2, [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10]]
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0] -> out = [2, [2, 1, 2], [3, 9, 10]]
# [0, 0, 0] -> out = [1, [3, 'start', 'end']]
# [1, 2, 3] -> out = [0]
```

Comment: o(n) is impossible, O(n) is the best we can do. Unless with n you mean something other than the list length?

Comment: n is the length of the list, why is it impossible? @KellyBundy

Comment: Because of course you need to at least look at all the numbers.

Comment: yes, I am looking at the numbers in the list one time. the length of the list is n so this algorithm is O(n), there are some other actions such as keeping track of the groups and the surrounding numbers but I'm talking about the loop over the list, I am looping over it 1 time so O(n) @KellyBundy

Comment: The output isn't what they expect, and your code doesn't even have the strings "start"/"end".

Comment: Yes, but you had said o(n), not O(n).

Comment: my mistake, please take a look at the new code @KellyBundy

Comment: Now it fails their example.

Comment: my bad I was missing a '=', now it's good @KellyBundy

Comment: Still fails two of the test cases in my answer.

Comment: my code passes your test cases, your code is wrong it considers 1 zero as a group which it shouldn't. @KellyBundy

Comment: That's an unusual view and the question doesn't say that, so it's likely wrong.